# Please translate the song title '떽떽이를 위한 노래' from the 허수 album '야자하기 싫은날' to English

Tags: translation

[image]
Can someone translate this song's title and album in English. I do think it's Korean.

Comment: There is actually quite a bit of idiomatic language that can be learned from this question. An unusual but intriguing question.

Comment: Here is a link to the album on iTunes: https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/%EC%95%BC%EC%9E%90%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0-%EC%8B%AB%EC%9D%80%EB%82%A0/id763229912

Comment: 야자 here is probably 야간자율학습, i.e. night time self-study, or keeping high school students at school after school. (Another song on the album refers to high school.) So the whole album would be: the day you don't want to do night time self-study. (That would be every day.)

Comment: @Catomic this seems like a likely answer.

Comment: 야자 is definitely 야간자율학습. Btw where can I hear the song?

Answer (score 7):

떽떽이를 위한 노래

- *떽떽거리다* means *speak loudly with stuck-upness*
- *~이* means *a person*. I think it's the same *~er* in English. So 떽떽이 means *someone who speaks loudly with stuck-upness.*
- But here, I think Vladhagen's explanation about 떽떽이 is more proper. We need to listen to the song for more exact meaning.
- *위한* means *for*. *노래* means *song*. So **떽떽이를 위한 노래** means **Song for 떽떽이.**

야자하기 싫은 날

- 야자 is acronym for 야간 자율학습. Many Korean high-school students study after classes. We call the study 야간 자율학습. Classes normally finish at 5 pm but many students study till 10 pm at the classroom to pass the top universities.
- *~하기 싫다* means *I don't wanna to do* ~.
- *날* means *day*. So **야자하기 싫은 날** means **The day I don't want to study.**

Side note : There is a game called 야자time. 야자time is the allowed time that people say without honorific. It's great rudeness to say without honorifics to elder people in South Korea but the rudeness is forgiven in 야자time. It's the game. This is not related to this situation, though.

Comment: Yes. This is a solid answer.

Answer (score 6):

The best I can come up with for the song is "Song for the Loud Mouth."
The "loud mouth" here is not a literal translation. I have tried to work the phrase "떽떽이" into meaningful English here. "떽떽이" is an idiom of sorts. I have heard it used on the context of a "loud mouth" or a person who cannot stop running their mouth.

The album title is also a bit hard to nuance. 야자하기 is probably referring to the act of speaking to one another informally like friends. Think of it sort of like using slang/familiar language. Korean is heavily based on using the correct register (politeness level) when speaking to someone. 야자 time refers to the times when you speak to people like close friends or in a familiar register.

If I had to make an attempt at translating the title, it would probably be something like "The Despicable Day of Speaking Informally to one Another". You could also frame it as "The Awful Day of Becoming Friends", or even "The Awful Day of Becoming Familiar".

This all assumes that the album is not speaking about "hating doing a coconut," which of course makes absolutely no sense.

Since a lot of idiomatic language is in play here, all of these translations sound forced and unnatural in English. Perhaps someone can produce a better rendering. The album name uses slang for a practice that English speaking countries do not have a word for really, hence the title of the album is a but hard to briefly translate accurately. (And it is even harder to accurately make it sound like an album with a "normal" English title).

Comment: Maybe one "normal" sounding album title translation would be "The Familiarity I Despise."

Comment: I think you don't know there are two kinds of 야자. One is for game. Another is for high-school. I think you are talking about the game. However, in this situation, 야자 is for high-school.

Comment: 야자 까기 싫은 날 would be 'the day you don't want to talk down.'

Comment: `hating doing a coconut` ㅎㅎㅎ

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be official English names for the songs. This turned up when I searched on Google, doesn't seem to be machine translated, but can't find the real source for now:

> - 야자하기 싫은날 [I Don't Want To Self-Study After School Had Finished]
>
>   1. 일어나보니 여덟시 (8 o'Clock)
>   2. 야자하기 싫은날 (I Don't Want To Self-Study After School Had Finished)
>   3. 떽떽이를 위한 노래 (A Song For Whiner)
>   4. 참비는 외계인 (Cham-Bi Is Alien)
>   5. 엄마와 다이소 (Daiso With Mom)
>   6. 고삐리 이학년 (Sophomore In High School)
>   7. 새벽 다섯 시 잠 못 들어 뒤척이는데 (5AM, Sleepless Night)

The whole album seems to be about high school life.